# Remove Top Bar area in iOS iPhone/iPad App

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uikit, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to remove the blank Top Bar area (see screenshot), above the "Become a better you". There should be no margin between the text and the top edge, but at runtime it seems to insert that space there. We're not showing a title or navigation bar, and would like to remove this space. Any ideas?

[image: screenshot with blank topbar area]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions guys. It turned out to be something else - the subview was centered, causing the gap at the top and bottom, because the subview was positioned based on bounds instead of frame.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your top constraint connects with superview's top, not with top layout guide.

Answer (score 1):

Frist You Try This Code  `UItabbar` Remove  One Pixel

[[UINavigationBar appearance]setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];

Second One IS

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"top"];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarPosition:UIBarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:image];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];

[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:FALSE];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

and `UIimageView` also use tha same Image 
[image]